# Get fitted values for new datapoints in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-science

I have some time series "ts" with weekly data and fit an arima model to it. This gives me the fitted values for the data points. Next week I have a new datapoint for the time series and would like to get a fitted value without training the arima model again. Can I use the information in my already trained model to get the fitted value for the new datapoint?

```
library(forecast)
library("dplyr")

timeseries <- ts(nhtemp)

# original timeseries and new timeseries with one additonal datapoint
timeseries_original <- nhtemp %>% head(-1)
timeseries_new <- nhtemp

# fit model
mod_arima <- auto.arima(timeseries_original)

# fitted values
mod_arima$fitted

# get fitted values for new data?
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution myself

```
mod_arima_new <- Arima(timeseries_new, model=mod_arima)
```